# No free space on ubuntu 16.04 running on virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I'm having hard times for a couple of weeks with this one...
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS as a dev web server, it's running on virtualbox (win7) and these "no free space" available are coming again and again.
I tried to remove every temp files, got it working for a few hours, then the same issue again (no surprise here). I googled it and tried to extend my disk size. I managed to extend it, allocate the new free space to my partition with gparted live cd (I'm running ubuntu in terminal mode, no startx installed)
I thought I walked through this, it worked well for a few days, then no free space again... I doubled the disk size, so I'm kind of lost here...

IMO, my disk should have enough free space... I must have missed something obvious...

df -h gives me :

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         981M     0  981M   0% /dev
tmpfs                        201M  3.3M  197M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  5.4G  5.0G   23M 100% /
tmpfs                       1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M  105M  343M  24% /boot
tmpfs                        201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/1000
```

[image: vm disk settings]
[image: gparted screenshot]

**EDIT:**
sudo du -ks /*

```
15940   /bin
104844  /boot
0       /dev
7072    /etc
895620  /home
0       /initrd.img
0       /initrd.img.old
636860  /lib
4       /lib64
16      /lost+found
8       /media
4       /mnt
4       /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/2921/task/2921/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2921/task/2921/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2921/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2921/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
16      /root
3332    /run
13232   /sbin
4       /snap
4       /srv
0       /sys
32      /tmp
1484508 /usr
2181768 /var
0       /vmlinuz
0       /vmlinuz.old
```

lsblk

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 14.7G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5                  8:5    0 14.2G  0 part
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0  5.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Find where the space is going.  Try `sudo du -ks /*` then drill down.  A very common such problem is large log files in `/var/log/...` which are not being rotated.  You might also add to your question the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: 5GB is not a lot of space for your root / partition.  If you free up a bit of space, you can install `gnome-utils` and launch the GNOME disk usage analyzer to see what is using up all your space.

Comment: @user4556274 post edited

Comment: Agree with @user4556274. `/var` is unusually large. Drill down (`sudo du -ks /var/*`, etc.) and find out what is causing it.

Comment: I agree with both of you, but in my gparted screenshot, I see I have 6.65Go unused. Why can't I use it ?

Comment: @ThEBiShOp, when you say that you "managed to extend [the virtual disk space]", did you increase the size of `/dev/sda5` without using `lvextend` to cause your lvm volume to expand to use the newly allocated space?

Comment: @user4556274 I used this command under win7 : VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB
then I used gparted to allocate the unallocated space to my main partition. Nothing else if I remember correctly

Comment: @ThEBiShOp, as you can see in both your `df -h` and `lsblk` output, you are not using `/dev/sda5` _directly_ as disk storage, but are using the lvm volume `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` contained on that virtual drive.  You need to use `lvextend` to increase that volume to use the full ~14Go in `/dev/sda5`.  I haven't done this recently enough to give a safe off-the-top-of-my-head command.  Check manpages, and ensure you have backups of anything valuable before going ahead.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1128398/how-to-increase-disk-size-allocation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-virtualbox-vm) is my answer on superuser regarding `lvextend`, with more detail.  Since you are not modifying swap, the `lvextend` in that answer should pretty well match what you need on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @user4556274, I read the answer he gave [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1128398/how-to-increase-disk-size-allocation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-virtualbox-vm), I just used the command :

```
sudo lvm lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

and I got the free space I needed

Comment: i had to run dpkg --configure -a  and apt-install lvm2 first

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu, you may consider to user "Disk Usage Analyzer" app which comes bundled with it. This gives better picture of usages and helps locate folders directly.

I was facing same issue and found that /var/tmp was almost using 90G of temporary files with the help of Disk Usage Analyzer.